# Copying a foreign key from one table to another to establish a one-to-many relationship

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am importing an excel table to access (large flat table: table_original with the following column (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K)). Then I go through a normalization step by distributing the data to  multiple tables to avoid redundancy.  After this step, I want to establish a one-to-many relationship between the data in the flat table and the data that I moved by adding a foreign key in the flat table so I can delete the attributes in the flat table

Here one example of the distribution step. I copy some column attributes from the flat table (table_original) to an existing table (table_dest)

```
db1.Execute "INSERT INTO table_dest (A, B, C, D, E)" _
    & " SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, D, E " _
    & " FROM table_original " _
    & " WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table_dest WHERE A = table_original.A)"
```

And this is working, then I want to add the new primary key from table_dest as foreign key in table_original so I can delete the attributes A, B, C, D and E in table_original.

So far I can only think of using recordset with an outer and inner loop to be able to add the foreign key to  matching data in table_original.  I am expecting a growing db.  This approach doesn’t seem very efficient.  Is there a better way? is there a way to add a foreign key in table_original as I copy the data from table_original to table_dest?

Comment: You can use the recordset approach, which might not be the most efficient solution, but it's easy to understand and maintain and it works. Another approach is to add a row_number column to all the tables, populate it with the row number of the original table, and use that to define the relationships between the various tables.

Comment: Thanks. I like the row number idea but as you mentioned the 2 loop brute force approach seems to be the safer to use

Comment: This import will be on-going, not a one-time effort? If the Excel file can be linked, then suggest you do that. Use it as source for recordsets. Then loop through recordset to save distinct master record, get its new ID and populate dependent table(s) with INSERT SELECT action sql.

Comment: This assumes the Excel does not have a natural key that can be used as pk/fk link.